# Not able to bind ng-repeat values in my custom directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have created custom-directive called ***displayId***. Using ng-repeat rendered custom-directive and bind id from ng-repeat data. Unfortunately not able to get id of element within custom directive.

```
    app.directive('displayId', function(){
          return {
                  restrict: 'EA',
                    compile: function(element){
                          alert(element.attr("id"));  //id displaying as op.id
                     }
         };
        });`
```

find the issue reproducible plnkr below.

https://plnkr.co/edit/3a8HBApCtbmYlGIfWyzM?p=preview

anyone please suggest me solution.

Comment: I guess compile method is before any parse to rendering HTML, so the value is the syntax using inside the directive before any return change inside the dom. `Note: The compile function $compile in the postLink function to imperatively compile a directive's template instead of relying on automatic template compilation via template or templateUrl declaration or manual compilation inside the compile function. ` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `compile` -> `post`

```
app.directive('displayId', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      compile: function(){

        return {
          pre: function ($scope, $elm, $attrs) {

          },
          post: function ($scope, $elm, $attrs, controllers) {
            console.log($attrs.id);
          }
        }

      }
    };
  });
```

<kbd>[Demo Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/po8WUmdSEWdu7Lbzyq12?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: yes i got it in post method. Is any other way to compile ng-repeat template in sample controller not in custom directive.

Comment: @Kbvin well, I think I answered on your question you published. About second question - its regards to what you want to achieve . I would ask different question in SO

Comment: @maxin i can get id using $attrs.id but when i access element its not compiled yet. how to compile that manually?  i m getting element as like `<display-id id="{{op.id}}"> </display-id>` but i need like `<display-id id="Title1"> </display-id>`

Comment: @Kbvin its really hard to explain in comments, please open new question with details and post here link. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

> You can pass scope in directive use link function of directive like
>   this

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="cntrl">
    <div ng-repeat="op in options">
        <p>{{op.id}}</p>
        <div displayid id={{op.id}} > </div>
    </div>    
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("cntrl",function($scope){

 $scope.options = [
    {'id' : 'Title1', 'label' : 'Zip code', 'type' : 'xxx' },
    {'id' : 'Title2', 'label' : 'MD', 'type' : 'title1'},
    {'id' : 'Title3', 'label' : 'DMS', 'type' : 'title2'}
];
})


app.directive('displayid', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope:{
        id:'@id'
      },
      link: function(scope,element,attrs){
        console.log(scope.id);
      }
    };
  });
</script>

</body>
```

<kbd>[Demo Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MkcdiwbwmztpAtCl1WYD?p=preview)</kbd>